# jailshell: composer: command not found

Tags: jail-shell

When I SSH into my server and run `composer install` it works without any issues. However when the command is issued from my CI/CD that would SSH on my server to get the changes I get this error:

```sh
jailshell: composer: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

---

My CI/CD:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh -tt user@domain.com
      "cd /path/to/public_html/ &&
      git checkout master &&
      git pull &&
      composer install &&
      exit"
```

### Edit

To answer @NicoHaase's question. There was a guide about adding an alias on my `.bashrc` but it still didn't work so I ended up downloading `composer.phar` and added it to my repository and instead of `composer install`, I use `php composer.phar install` instead. I mean it works now but that's not the solution to this question so I'm not writing that as an answer.

Comment: @NicoHaase added my answer to your question.